# No divider in suggestion list of SearchView

Tags: java, android, listview, searchview

I followed the example of Google about [custom suggestion](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html). My project is very simple:

1. One `ContentProvider.class`
2. One `SqlOpenHelper.class`
3. One `MainActivity.class`
4. One `menu` and one `layout`, no other XML layout/drawable is created.

I have a `SearchView` (support.v7) in the `Toolbar` of `AppCompatActivity` (AppCompat.v7) and tested with Android 5.1.1 and Android 4.3.

The `SearchView` in the menu is simple:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="Search"/>
  </menu>
```

It is able to get the suggestion from a simple `CustomContentProvider`. However, there is no divider in the suggestion list (see the image). Before I also created a similar search function in a normal layout of another app. It worked normally but this time the SearchView is in the Menu/Toolbar.

[image]

I was able to change the background of the suggestion list with this code:

```
private void initSearchView(MenuItem searchItem) {
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchableInfo searchableInfo = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

    SearchView.SearchAutoComplete autoCompleteTextView = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);

    /**
     * Todo: Change row style of suggestion List
     */
    if (autoCompleteTextView != null) { 
    autoCompleteTextView.setDropDownBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.search_suggestion_row));
    }
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchableInfo);
}
```

I have tried by changing the theme of `Activity` with no luck and I don't think I should create a row layout and a `ListAdapter` again.

Any solution for changing the style of the row or show the divider. Thanks for any help!

Comment: are you using a list view to show data and which version of android are you using

Comment: I tested on Android 5.1.1.

Comment: have you disabled the individual list item clicks

Comment: Where is that? I have no idea where to disable it. I have only a sime `searchable` and a `contentprovider`.

Comment: Have you changed divider height in xml

Comment: try changing divider color in xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The divider is not appearing because it a **bug in lollipop**, if you override the `**isEnabled()**` method this happens, here refer this and you can know more.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=83055

Comment: I didn't touch anything and I didn't create 'ListView' or 'ListAdapter'. I created only a content provider class and `sqlOpenHelper`. I also tested on Android 4.3 but the result is still the same. Am I missing the row layout?